# How is погода (weather) a count noun?

Tags: словоупотребление, значения, множественное-число

Wiktionary [says](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0) that the word **погода** (weather) has a plural form: **погоды**.

I see in Google that although the word is usually used in the singular form, the plural form is used either. For example, here is a quote from a book by Chekhov, a classic Russian writer:

> Хорошие погоды нынче стоят! ([Source](http://svadba-dzr.ru/kultura/%C2%ABkhoroshie-pogody-nynche-stoyat-li-chayu-vypit-khochetsya-li-udavitsya%C2%BB))

Literally, the above sentence means, "Good weathers now stand," and such a formulation appears weird to me.

Could you explain the logic and usage of the plural form of **погода**? In particular, I would like to know the precise meaning of the above phrase and why Chekhov chose the plural form.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Погоды [стоят]* means "the weather during several days". The [most famous instance](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=6qk5eFoJCJQC&pg=PA104&dq="%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5"+%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C+%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B5%D0%B2&hl=uk&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj069-ggu_kAhXmoYsKHW-YDi8Q6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%22%20%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B5%D0%B2&f=false) of that 'weather in plural' used in a work of fiction is in [Двенадцать стульев](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Twelve_Chairs) ('The Twelve Chairs'), a classic satirical novel about con artists by the Odessan Soviet authors Ilf and Petrov, published in 1928:

> Теперь такие *погоды* замечательные.

In the [classic 1971 Soviet film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Twelve_Chairs_(1971_film)) after the novel, the phrase was a bit changed and became

> Сейчас такие дивные *погоды* стоят!

Here is the fragment from the film where it is said: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r4nVtiN99H8

Most of the modern usage of *погоды* (pl.), is just quoting or paraphrasing that film episode, not the book, and surely not Chekhov.

Outside of that phrase, nobody uses *погода* in plural, as far as I know.

Comment: Слово "погоды" встречается в книге "Записки капитана Василия Головнина о приключениях его в плену у японцев". Это начало XIX века. Думаю, что сейчас это слово устарело.

Comment: @Elena - Безусловно. Да и «12 стульев» — это таки 1928 год.

Comment: В именительном падеже "погоды", почти не употребляются во мн. числе, зато в родительном,  судя по ruscorpora "погод" встречается часто.

Answer (score 6):

*Mitsuko, you seem to have developed the talent of stumbling upon 'false quotes' (remember your Bismark question?)*

*Disclaimer*: I realize that this is not an answer to the question about the plural form of **погода**. Might add something on this later on. I just find it quite interesting that this rather popular citation from Chekhov cannot actually be found in any of his works.

["Хорошие погоды нынче стоят! То ли чаю выпить хочется, то ли удавиться."](https://zen.yandex.ru/media/philological_maniac/gorko-i-smeshno-5-zabavnyh-citat-chehova-5c27150771a4ff00abd1e3cf)

> Фразой из пьесы «Дядя Ваня» до сих пор подписывают фотографии в
>   соцсетях, но в измененном виде. Ее превратили в предложение, где автор
>   якобы говорит о том, что день прекрасный, и можно или выпить кружку
>   чая, или повеситься.
>   Такой цитаты у Чехова нет, зато в пьесе один из
>   героев в диалоге говорит: «В такую погоду хорошо повеситься».

From "Дядя Ваня":

> …
>   Войницкий. **Я молчу. Молчу и извиняюсь.**
>               *Пауза.*
>   Елена Андреевна. **А хорошая сегодня погода... Не жарко...**
>               *Пауза.*
>   Войницкий. **В такую погоду хорошо повеситься...**

**Edit**:

As to "appears weird to me" - it does not sound particularly weird for a Russian ear. As @YellowSky mentions in the very first sentence, this can quite naturally be understood as the weather observed for a period of several days.
After all people do say "сегодня хорошая погода, а вчера была плохая погода", so here we go - хорошие погоды нынче стоят..
But people don't speak like this these days other than to make a bit of a joke (*actually, I use погоды from time to time myself and I have no idea where I picked this up. I think this was long before I had read or seen "The 12 chairs" but that's impossible to verify anyway*).

Answer (score 5):

> Could you explain the logic and usage of the plural form of погода?

*Погода* is a regular noun (ж 1а by Zaliznyak's classification), and so it has plural just like any (or should I say many?) other.

As your quote from "Checkhov" turns out to be fake, here is one from Kuprin's "The Garnet Bracelet":

> В середине августа, перед рождением молодого месяца, вдруг наступили *отвратительные погоды*, какие так свойственны северному побережью Чёрного моря.

As you see, "weathers" are just "weathers" and nothing else.